# WebRTC client failing on opensslidentity make certificate for webrtc

Tags: android, openssl, webrtc

I am developing webrtc client for android using the WebRTC Demo app.
While I have used the org.webrtc library to develop the client, I am facing issues when running my own client.

When I run my client, below is the logcat (part of complete logcat) I am getting

```
2-10 18:32:49.260 7669-9530/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:47): Making key pair
02-10 18:32:49.261 7669-9531/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1127): Signaling thread JavaCallback
02-10 18:32:49.261 7669-9531/org.appspot.apprtc I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onSignalingThreadReady
02-10 18:32:49.261 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: Peer connection factory created.
02-10 18:32:49.263 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: Create peer connection.
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: PCConstraints: mandatory: [], optional: [DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true]
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: VideoConstraints: mandatory: [minWidth: 1280, maxWidth: 1280, minHeight: 720, maxHeight: 720, minFrameRate: 30, maxFrameRate: 30], optional: []
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: EGLContext: org.webrtc.EglBase14$Context@35e6316b
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1382): Set EGL context for HW encoding.
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc I/MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideoEncoderFactory::SetEGLContext
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1391): Set EGL context for HW decoding.
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc I/MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideoDecoderFactory::SetEGLContext
02-10 18:32:49.265 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9527 (Thread-13274)
```

When I am running the WebRTC Demo app, I am getting the below logcat:

```
02-10 18:34:44.849 9621-10486/org.appspot.apprtc D/de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection: WebSocket connection created.
02-10 18:34:44.850 9621-9621/org.appspot.apprtc D/CallRTCClient: Creating peer connection, delay=754ms
02-10 18:34:44.858 9621-9621/org.appspot.apprtc D/CallRTCClient: Creating OFFER...
02-10 18:34:45.031 9621-10500/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:88): Returning key pair
02-10 18:34:45.031 9621-10500/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:95): Making certificate for WebRTC
02-10 18:34:45.034 9621-10500/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:143): Returning certificate
02-10 18:34:45.035 9621-10500/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1123): Worker thread JavaCallback
02-10 18:34:45.035 9621-10500/org.appspot.apprtc I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onWorkerThreadReady
02-10 18:34:45.037 9621-10501/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1127): Signaling thread JavaCallback
02-10 18:34:45.037 9621-10501/org.appspot.apprtc I/org.webrtc.Logging: PeerConnectionFactory: onSignalingThreadReady
02-10 18:34:45.037 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: Peer connection factory created.
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found target encoder for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp8 : OMX.qcom.video.encoder.vp8. Color: 0x15
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: Create peer connection.
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: PCConstraints: mandatory: [], optional: [DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: true]
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: VideoConstraints: mandatory: [minWidth: 1280, maxWidth: 1280, minHeight: 720, maxHeight: 720], optional: []
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc D/PCRTCClient: EGLContext: org.webrtc.EglBase14$Context@322112a
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1382): Set EGL context for HW encoding.
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc I/MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideoEncoderFactory::SetEGLContext
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (peerconnection_jni.cc:1391): Set EGL context for HW decoding.
02-10 18:34:45.040 9621-10498/org.appspot.apprtc I/MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideoDecoderFactory::SetEGLContext
```

My client is crashing on a point

```
02-10 18:32:49.264 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc I/MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideo: MediaCodecVideoDecoderFactory::SetEGLContext
02-10 18:32:49.265 7669-9527/org.appspot.apprtc A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9527 (Thread-13274)
```

But the WebRTC Demo runs properly.
The difference which I have observed is below:
My client is not able to make `opensslidentity` `certificate for WebRTC` as can be seen from the logcat.
My client is stuck at

```
2-10 18:32:49.260 7669-9530/org.appspot.apprtc I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:47): Making key pair
```

However, the demo app is able to do that.

I like know why my client is not able to make the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happening when I was not using the Ice Server. After passing the Ice Server to PeerConnection, the app works properly